# Can a managed switch with VLANS have multiple identical subnets?

Tags: switch, vlan

And if so, what is this feature called?

In a plant floor setting I would like to simplify the a printing systems for the maintenance folks.

Each station consists of a very small form factor Windows 7/10 PC and an Ethernet printer. The PC has a single Ethernet port and cannot be easily expanded to two.

Right now each PC and printer has an manually assigned network IP address. The installed printer drivers have ports assigned to the printer for that particular line and spare printer.

The problem comes when things get shifted do to repairs or testing. Over time as the number of units have increased it is getting harder to manage each station as replacing a computer or printer requires a lot of reconfiguration.

I would like to simplify the process by doing the following:

1. Set the PC to DHCP and have the DHCP server set a fixed IP via the MAC.
2. Set a secondary fixed address on the Ethernet card in all the computers to some public IP (Ex: 192.168.1.1)
3. Set all the printers for all lines to the same address such on that network such as 192.168.1.2

This is the step I don't know if it can be done with a managed switch:

4. Configure pairs of ports on the switch to separate VLANs so that each pair share the same 192.168.1.0 subnet. The means that the printer on port 2 and the printer on port 4 do not overlap because they are on separate VLANs but have the same address. We do not expect to be able to reach the printers from outside their paired PC.
5. Allow the main LAN traffic on the network to reach the PC via its primary DHCP assigned address.
6. Repeat on additional pairs of ports for additional stations.

This question is meant to determine if it this is a valid feature of smart manged switches or is strictly a routing problem.

Comment: A managed switch will not help you.  I can think of some convoluted ways to make this work, but they are more complicated than what you're doing now.  What do you need to reconfigure besides the address of the printer?

Comment: As far as the computer is concerned its making sure the right IP is in the driver configuration. Printing to another printer by accident would be very bad, Then there is the paper work that needs to be done to track it where those printer IPs are living.

Comment: Can a Win 7/10 computer be configured for dhcp AND have a static secondary?  I've never tried it.,

Comment: Yes. In the IPV4 settings for the card there is an Advanced... button. On the dialog that opens you can set additional network addresses and gateways,

Comment: @Run Trunk So you are saying that the switches generally prevent you from making VLANs with duplicate networks.

Comment: Using identical subnets effectively prevents any communication between those VLANs and with the "main LAN". (It _is_ possible but you don't want to do that.) Setting up a DHCP server with various scopes and reservations with each subnet shouldn't be too hard. If you want to prevent inter-VLAN communication yet permit central management of the printers for instance, you'll need a firewall and appropriate rules.

Comment: No. VLANs and IP addresses operate at different layers. If the VLANs were isolated, you could get away with this.  But since you also want Internet access, you would need a layer 3 switch or router to route all those VLANs to the Internet.   If you're going to reserve MAC addresses in your DHCP server, I don't see why statics are a disadvantage.

Comment: @RonTrunk: you can set Win7 to use DHCP and it that fails fall back to a static address ("alternative configuration") but not both at the same time.

Comment: @Zac67, well, that shoots down that idea.

Comment: The printers are on the subnet that is duplicated and they absolutely will not be talking to anything except its partner PC.  The partner PC has both a DHCP assigned address that has a gatweay and the fixed address that is on the printer's subnet.  The computers will not talk to any of the other printers other than it's partner.

Comment: I can confirm that DHCP does lock out the ability to add a second address manually, but having both set manual allows me to have the PC talk to the printer and access normal LAN as desired.

Comment: Probably I don't get the scenario here - but I'd put the printers into a single VLAN/subnet, put the PCs somewhere else, reserve static IPs for everything and set up firewall rules to allow a 1:1 printing. Easy peasy.

Comment: The idea is to have all printers with the same IP address so that maintenance can swap them at the line and not have to worry about changing the computer configuration. This is a production line scenario where nothing needs to access the printer except the one computer next to it.

Comment: This should be the simplest solution without investing in parts and mechanical labor.   If the computer had a second NIC, or a free USB port to add a second NIC we could do a peer to peer connection.  The computer is also in an enclosure so a second Ethernet connector would need to be added to the case to be able to connect the second NIC to the printer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your scenario seems plausible and possible. The switch should not have issues with the same subnet being used on multiple VLANs because it doesn't even look at the "Subnet" or Layer 3 contents of the frames. Its job is to just forward frames into their proper broadcast domains.

But of course if you are using multiple VLANs for each pair, the primary DHCP scopes must be separate for each VLAN and the DHCP setup will be the tricky part here since, you either need to have a VLAN interface and a DHCP helper/relay IP on each primary subnet for each VLAN.

Comment: It looks like DHCP will be out. Windows 7 and up do not allow DHCP and a secondary IP address. The router that the switch connects to will not be able to resolve the subnet used by the printers, but that is desired. It will understand the computers primary address and that is desired.

Comment: Yes, this whole scenario is only valid under the assumption that you can actually configure secondary addresses of your choice when the primary configuration is set to DHCP and not manual addressing. I had a feeling this wasn't possible in Windows 7 (or any Windows version for that matter)

Comment: Since they already manually assign addresses it won't be too much of a hardship to continue and add the second address.  DHCP was a wish list item..